# How can I check the current value of an input with eventemitter?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, eventemitter

I have a reusable Angular component that includes a text input. This component simply takes in a function to handle its @Output value.

I want to add a CSS class to this component as long as the text input is populated. I got it to work, but it feels wrong to use both an observable and a class value (searchQuery and searchQuery$ in the code snippet) in order to track the input. How can I improve this code?

Here is the HTML with the input. Notice the icon checks the observable to see if it should include the "focused" class:

```
<input #input placeholder="Search services..." (change)="setSearchQuery($event.target.value)" />
<div class="icon-container" (click)="outputSearchQuery(searchQuery)">
  <i [class]="!(searchQuery$ | async) ? 'fa fa-search search-icon' : 'fa fa-search search-icon focused'"></i>
</div>
```

And here is the TS file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.scss'],
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() submit: any = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @ViewChild('input') protected input: ElementRef;

  public searchQuery: string = '';
  public searchQuery$: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchQuery$ = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(map((event: any) => event.target.value));
  }

  public setSearchQuery(newVal: string) {
    this.searchQuery = newVal;
  }

  public outputSearchQuery() {
    this.submit.emit(this.searchQuery);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I got what you're trying to do. Any reason to use `Observable`? Take a look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-phxk6s

Comment: @developer033 yep that's what I had initially, but I want to add a CSS class to the icon whenever "searchQuery" is populated. Without using an observable, the CSS class only updates when I unfocus the input

Comment: Please, check it now by reloading the stackblitz.

Comment: @developer033 This seems very promising, but do you know how to do it using ReactiveFormsModule?

Comment: Check it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-swdpfd

Comment: @developer033 Not only does it work but the entire code is a lot cleaner. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :). As a final tip, I'd recommend you to NOT name your `emitter` as `submit` or any other native HTML event. Check out [codelyzer](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer) (the rule `no-output-native` was done exactly to deal with such cases).